# How to create json object local to loop into this View please

Tags: react-native

```js
class ProductCategory extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <Text style={styles.categoryViewHeaderTitle}>
              Product Categories
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.categoryView}>
              <CategoryBox
                width={width}
                source={{
                  uri: 'ect',
                }}
                name="The Cozy Room"
                type="PRIVATE ROOM - 2 BEDS"
                price={82}
                rating={4}
              />
              <CategoryBox
                width={width}
                source={{
                  uri: 'ect',
                }}
                name="The Cozy Room"
                type="PRIVATE ROOM - 2 BEDS"
                price={82}
                rating={4}
              />
              <CategoryBox
                width={width}
                source={{
                  uri: 'ect',
                }}
                name="The Cozy Room"
                type="PRIVATE ROOM - 2 BEDS"
                price={82}
                rating={4}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe:

```js
class ProductCategory extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: [
        {
          width: 200,
          source: { uri: 'ect' },
          name: 'The Cozy Room',
          type: 'PRIVATE ROOM - 2 BEDS',
          price: 82,
          rating: 4,
        },
        {
          width: 200,
          source: { uri: 'ect' },
          name: 'The Cozy Room',
          type: 'PRIVATE ROOM - 2 BEDS',
          price: 82,
          rating: 4,
        },
        {
          width: 200,
          source: { uri: 'ect' },
          name: 'The Cozy Room',
          type: 'PRIVATE ROOM - 2 BEDS',
          price: 82,
          rating: 4,
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
            <Text style={styles.categoryViewHeaderTitle}>
              Product Categories
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.categoryView}>
              {this.state.arr.map((m) => (
                <CategoryBox {...m} />
              ))}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

OR

```js
{
  this.state.arr.map((m) => (
    <CategoryBox
      width={m.width}
      source={m.source}
      name={m.name}
      type={m.type}
      price={m.price}
      rating={m.rating}
    />
  ));
}
```